# Mysql subqueries inside a limit clause

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have a subquery inside a limit clause in mysql? I am trying to select only 10% of the total number of rows from the same table in just one query.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT (SELECT (10 * COUNT(*)/100) FROM table);
```

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to randomly select about 10% of the rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE rand() < 0.1;
```

It is not 100% precise, but it works well-enough for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is it possible to have a subquery inside a limit clause in mysql?

The answer is basically no.

Read this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:
>
> Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ?
>   placeholder markers.
>
> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `user variables` if you need `TOP 10%` as follows.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT @seq := @seq + 1 AS seq, table.* FROM table, (SELECT @seq := 0) AS init1,
    (SELECT @ten_percent := (SELECT (10 * COUNT(*)/100) FROM table)) AS init2
) x
WHERE seq < @ten_percent;
```